# ruby win32api cluster

Tags: ruby, winapi

I am trying to use win32api in ruby and manage the clusapi-

```
require "Win32API"  

OpenCluster = Win32API.new('clusapi','OpenCluster',['P'], 'L')
OpenCluster.call('cc-fs01')

CreateClusterGroup = Win32API.new('clusapi','CreateClusterGroup',['P','P'], 'L')
CreateClusterGroup.call ('cc-fs01','testing')
```

This is run with admin rights and it exits with no errors, but it does not do anything.
I have tried similar activity with win32/api and ffi but to no avail.  I'd prefer not to use mscluster_cluster via ole since that is deprecated. That does work  My guess is that is has something to do with the handle, but I am not a c guy. This is the function- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369315(v=vs.85).aspx

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: I don't have time to run it on my own.  But your call to CreateClusterGroup is not correct (which you probably guessed).  You need to capture the return value from OpenCluster and pass that handle as the first parameter to CreateClusterGroup.

Answer (score 0):

you are correct, but the real issue, is that the names, groups, resources, etc, have to been .encode('UTF-16LE')